# user id which initiated script

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a website  on wordpress platform. I have strange issues caused by user id.
It is this the user who initiated the script:

```
global $user_ID;
```

what i mean is, when somebody go to a page, and php executes, so i need to know the user id in php when code executes. For some reasons, sometime the id is not right.

also when php script is executing , if i do:

```
global $user_ID =  get_current_user_id();
```

then i have the user id which initiated this script ?

Comment: Why are you setting this as a global variable?  You should not need to, and when you say the user id is not right, what do you mean by that?  In what way is it not right?  Are you not getting anything?  Getting a different existing user?  Or just some random number?

Comment: Only logged in users will have a user_id we need to see more of the code that has the issue as it could be any number of potential problems from that little one liner

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in strpos(), this is not a smart function, it not able to find a substring:

```
strpos($text,'{"user":"'.$user_ID.'","status":"2"}');
```

But substr_count() worked. And this is not my first time when strpos() fault... i will no more use it.